# Laravel: Select is not displayed in the form

Tags: select, laravel-5.8

So my problem is that the Select does not exist in my form, and have no idea why?

I've tried other pages and always have the same result, missing the select field.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
<form action="customers" method="POST" class="pb-3">


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" class="form-control">
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email: </label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" class="form-control">
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="active">Status: </label>
    <select name="active" class="form-control doom">
        <option value="" disabled>Select status</option>
        <option value="1">Active</option>
        <option value="0">Inactive</option>
    </select>
    </div><br>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Customer</button>

    @csrf
</form>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I can see two input fields but not the select field, all I can see is the label of the select field.

Comment: what's the purpose of using doom css class in the select field?

Comment: Check it in developer tool whether it got rendered or not and in display show mode

Comment: The boom class is just to check if the css code has any effect on the select field, but it does not have and is the same with or without the class.

Comment: @RajkumarR thank you, I found one of the CSS links with display set to none for the select field.